# Sql Server SHRINKDATABASE command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-administration

When I shrink a sql server database using the GUI (All Tasks->Shrink Database->Accept all defaults, click OK), it finishes quickly.

But if I run this command, it takes a very very long time.

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE('my_database')
```

What am I missing?

This is in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly the interface will leave about 20% grown space, running DBCC SHRINKDATABASE without any parameters shrinks it to as small as possible.

I don't have Enterprise Manager handy to check the defaults.  But you should notice a smaller database file with the manual run than the GUI run, thus the time difference

Comment: The gui default is actually to leave 0% free space.

Comment: odd, mine is set to 20%, but who knows what happened there.

Comment: hm, maybe someone set it to 0% in the past and it saved the pref.  anyway, it is fast in the gui and slow from Query Analyzer.

Comment: doing some checking, I can't see anything that would support the difference, other than some potential optimization of the interface on the GUI side.

Comment: Thanks, it is really odd, I'm googling far and wide, and I get nothing for sure.  How much of a time difference are we talking?

Comment: From the GUI it took about 5 seconds, from Query Analyzer it was "go get a cup of coffee and chat with a co-worker" slow.  Probably 15 mins or so.

Answer (score -2):

Details about the DBCC SHRINKDATABASE can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx. Notice this is for SQL Server 2005 ->

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide any information that actually answers the question. If you link to some article, at least summarize what information in there answers the original question.